# How to use the JComponent

Tags: java

I'm very new to programming. I just started today and am following a book called learning java by Patrick Neimeyer and Daniel Leuck.

It started by asking me to create the Hello World ! programme, and did this by placing it in a JFrame which was all done in one class, it is now asking me two create another class in which will use a JComponent. I've tried creating another class and have just ended up going around in circles with errors.

This is my previous attempt. Can someone explain please what I'm meant to do?! I know it is fairly basic, but I am struggling.

It's telling me that the new code for the class is:

```
import java.awt.*;

class HelloComponent extends JComponent {

    public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
        g.drawString( "Hello, Java!", 125, 95 );
    }
}
```

Where do I add this?

Comment: **Hint**: Initialize your HelloComponent and at it in your JFrame.

Comment: Start with examining some example programs which are **very** easy to find.

Comment: When you start learning programming today, then I am kinda wondering why you are already dealing with UI stuff. Seems like a very challenging start to me. I would rather recommend to start here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ ... and work the "basics" trails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather perplexing way to start programming in Java. Even so, in this instance why would you not use a JLabel rather than creating your own JComponent?

In any case, as some of the comments already said, you need to add your JComponent to a JFrame.

An example below:

**Example JFrame class**
This class extends JFrame rather than creating and using a JFrame object. It also includes the main method as well, just to avoid another class. The main method runs the GUI on the event dispatch thread. This part is important, but not so much for a beginner.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ExampleFrame extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ExampleFrame frame = new ExampleFrame();
                frame.createAndShow();
            }
        });
    }

    public void createAndShow() {
        getContentPane().add(new HelloComponent());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Hello World Example");
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

**HelloComponent**

As before with your version, but sets the preferred size so that when the JFrame is 'packed' it sizes to the component. Additionally, I've used the `Graphic` font height metric to position the y-coordinate, since the `drawString` method places the y coordinate at the bottom left.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class HelloComponent extends JComponent {

    private final int COMPONENT_WIDTH = 100;
    private final int COMPONENT_HEIGHT = 30;

    public HelloComponent() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(COMPONENT_WIDTH, COMPONENT_HEIGHT));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString("Hello World", 0, g.getFontMetrics().getHeight());
    }
}
```